# Can I get bright detail and dark background photos using a phone camera and basic editing?

Tags: lighting, tutorial, low-key

What is the term for this type of photography? Can I get this effect using a phone camera and basic editing? Are there tutorials to achieve this?

[image: This is the photo]
<sub>(source: [normanow.com](http://normanow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FSOB_BaePhotos_16.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> Can I get bright detail and dark background photos using a phone camera and basic editing?

Answering the question literally, **no**. The key element of this type of photography is not particular to any camera technology (be it camera phone or professional medium-format camera), nor is it particular to a particular type of post-processing.

The key feature of this type of photography is *lighting*. Specifically, this is an example of [low-key lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-key_lighting). The term is somewhat counterintuitive, because it refers to the *high ratio* of lighting of the brightest elements of the scene to the darkest elements (usually the background) of the scene.

So, can you achieve this look with your phone camera and post-processing? Sure, but **only if you control the lighting** of the subject, some distance from the background. With a powerful enough key light, the background doesn't have to even be black – the key light will overpower any light hitting the background. However, to make it easier on yourself, and probably less expensive, it helps to control as many elements of the scene lighting as possible: strong key light, dark background, gobos to block incident and reflected light.